# Right SQLite query syntax in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I must get the rows of a database according the passed parameters

for example, select all people sorted by name that are 38years old, and are artists female,
the passed parameters are

```
String age=38;
String gender=female;
String job=artist;
```

I have tried to write this but surely there is a syntax error in my rawQuery

```
public Cursor getData(String age, String gender, String job) {
        try {
            Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable order by Name asc WHERE Age='"+age+"'"  WHERE Gender='"+gender+"'" WHERE Job='"+job+"'", null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getData>>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }

    }
```

Someone could help meto fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Age is type String try:

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Age LIKE \""+age+"\" AND Gender LIKE \""+gender+"\" AND Job LIKE \""+job+"\" order by Name asc", null);
```

If Age is type Integer try:

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Age = \""+age+"\" AND Gender LIKE \""+gender+"\" AND Job LIKE \""+job+"\" order by Name asc", null);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your SQL syntax. The ORDER BY clause should come at the end. Multiple conditions should be joined by the AND keyword, not multiple WHEREs. Finally, your quotes are not properly matched.

Below is the proper SQL query:

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Age LIKE '"+age+"' AND Gender LIKE '"+gender+"' AND Job LIKE '"+job+"' ORDER BY Name ASC;

Comment: Like @Luis pointed out, these are strings you are comparing, so the LIKE operator should be used. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ( Age = ?  and Gender = ? and Job= ? )  order by Name asc",new String[]{age,gender,job})